# Reduction as a flowchart

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, reductions

I'm trying to understand the reduction as a flowchart graph.
[image]

Let's say the boxes $A$ and $B$ are TMs/Functions and $x$ is the input.
Is this plot represent reduction from $A$ to $B$ ($A\le B$) or from $B$ to $A$ ($B\le A$)?
Or maybe it can be both of the way depending on the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that $f:\Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$ is a reduction from $A\subseteq \Sigma^*$ to $B\subseteq \Sigma^*$. A flowchart graph of $f$ looks like:

[image]

Indeed, $f$ maps all words in $A$ to $B$, and all words in $\overline{A}$ to $\overline{B}$.

The closest flowchart to the image that you attached corresponds to the reduction theorem, to be explined below. (You explicitly stated that the rectangles in the graph correspond to machines).

**The Reduction Theorem:** if there is a reduction from $A$ to $B$, then it holds that i) $B\in \text{R} \to A\in \text{R}$, and ii)$B\in \text{RE} \to A \in \text{RE}$.

**Sketch of The Proof:** The proof of the theorem goes as follows. Let $M_f$ be a machine that computes a reduction $f$ from $A$ to $B$, and let $M_B$ be a machine that decides (recognizes, respectively) $B$. Then, a machine $M_A$ that decides (recognizes, respectively) $A$ operates as follows. On input $x$, $M_A$ computes $f(x)$, and then it simulates the run of $M_B$ on $f(x)$ and answers the same. The following is the flowchart corresponding to the proof. [image]

Note that in both graphs, the arrow is to the rectangle corresponding to the language we are reducing to, $B$.

Comment: Thanks great answer! I just wrote a follow-up question to your answer

Answer (score 1):

The arrow is going from $A$ to $B$. It means you are solving problem $A$ using problem $B$. So, it is a reduction from $A$ to $B$